# how to display images by using ALAsseetLibrary

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, alassetslibrary

I am accessing the list of images by using the ALAssetLibrary and i got the list of all image in log file . But i am unable to display any image. Can anyone help me through this?

For getting the list of all images my code is here---

```
- (IBAction)getListOfImages:(id)sender {

NSMutableArray* assetURLDictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *xy =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

void (^assetEnumerator)( ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    if(result != nil) {
        if([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto]) {
            [assetURLDictionaries addObject:[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs]];

            NSLog(@"result is:%@",result);
            NSLog(@"asset URLDictionary is:%@",assetURLDictionaries);
            NSURL *url= (NSURL*) [[result defaultRepresentation]url];

            [library assetForURL:url
                     resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                         [xy addObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]]];
                         NSLog(@" xy is:%@",xy);
                         UIImageView *image =[ [UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage:[xy objectAtIndex:0]];
                         NSLog(@"image is:%@",image);
                     }
                    failureBlock:^(NSError *error){ NSLog(@"test:Fail"); } ];
        }
    }
};

NSMutableArray *assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
void (^ assetGroupEnumerator) ( ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *)= ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"hello");
    if(group != nil) {
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
        [assetGroups addObject:group];
        NSLog(@"Number of assets in group :%d",[group numberOfAssets]);
        NSLog(@"asset group is:%@",assetGroups);
    }
};

assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                       usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                     failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                         NSLog(@"A problem occurred");
                     }];
}
```

Comment: You can use this for get all images..github link. .     https://github.com/sgxiang/YSQImagePickerController

Comment: I just want to display the images by using the ALAssetLibrary @Milanpatel